# NSDocument wide variable

Tags: cocoa, backend, nsdocument

so i need a NSDocument with a backend instance that all views can access and the objects in the backend can access. At the moment i've got a shared instance, but this limits the document to only one. the code is simply like this:

```
static id sharedInstance = nil;

+(void)initialize {
    if (self == [ApricumBackend class]) {
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];       
    }
}
+ (id)mainBackend {
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

But this doesn't work the way i want it to. So how can i achieve that one NSDocument has one variable every view can access and how can i get every object in the backend to be able access the backend? I've made a little graph:
[image: an awesome graph]

Important is also that the objects in the backend object need to have access to the backend object while they "init"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the objects, you create a common subclass of `NSObject` that includes the designated initializer:

```
+ (id)initWithBackend:(Backend *)backend;
```

Perhaps call it `BackendObject`. Then your objects should subclass `BackendObject` and add initializer methods which are appropriate, for example:

```
+ (id)initWithSomething:(Something *)something backend:(Backend *)backend;
```

These initializer methods can then call the superclass initializer, and the backend object (which the graph shows as owning them) needs to pass `self` when it initializes them.

For the views, you can access the document from within the `NSView` subclass initializer using:

```
MyDocument *mydoc = [[[self window] windowController] document];
```

And provide an accessor to get to the backend, which can be held as an instance variable:

```
Backend *backend = [mydoc backend];
```